# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational namespace (using) won't resolve

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm using EF as my ORM, and I need to execute some raw SQL against my postgres DB, to offload some JSON (jsonb) processing.

I'm using EntityFramework Core 1.1.0, with the npgsql provider for postgres.  Per the latest docs on executing SQL, I need to use context.[entity].FromSql() - where FromSql is in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational namespace.

So, I added that package via NuGet...  The screenshot shows the problem - the reference is added, but it won't resolve in my code:

[image: Namespace not resolving]

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Core SDK and VS developer tools (VS 2015).  Any help appreciated.

Edit, showing full reference:
[Full reference screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osXYH.png)

Comment: From your screenshot it would seem you added Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational as a DLL dependency and not as a regular nuget... Can you try simply adding a nuget dependency instead?

Comment: @ShayRojansky thanks for looking - I added a second screenshot - just needed to scroll up in solution explorer...

Comment: Reference and namespace are different things. The `RelationalQueryableExtensions` class you are seeking is located in the showed referenced assembly under `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace.

Comment: Well, hell.  :-)  Thanks @IvanStoev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Reference and namespace are different things. The
>   RelationalQueryableExtensions class you are seeking is located in the
>   showed referenced assembly under Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
>   namespace.

@IvanStoev was correct.  The reference added the .FromSql extension to my entities after including the base Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore namespace.